# Immunity Debugger Unable to set Breakpoint

Tags: debugging, debuggers, anti-debugging, immunity-debugger

I have recently installed Immunity Debugger in order to do some dynamic analysis on some Malware however am getting the same 2 errors no matter what i try.

1. The first error is that Immunity is **'Unable to set a breakpoint'** this is set to the default WinMain function.
2. The second is that Immunity is **'Unable to write back modified registers'**.

I originally suspected that there may have been some Anti-Debug tactics involved however have come to realise that is not the case after implementing some plugins that circumvent that type of protection.

Scratching my head here as i cant seem to find anyone with the same issue as me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What Malware? What type of "plugins" do you use? Did you already countercheck these related references [1](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8442/anti-debugging-techniques-preventing-me-from-setting-a-memory-and-hardware-bre) 
[2](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6124/why-was-my-memory-breakpoint-not-triggered-in-ollydbg?rq=1) 
[3](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/are-there-any-ollydbg-anti-debug-anti-anti-debug-plugins-what-work-with-windows) [4](http://waleedassar.blogspot.de/2012/11/defeating-memory-breakpoints.html)?